# tr insert after ajax request

Tags: jquery, tr, closest, insertafter

I'm kinda new to jQuery and just created the following:
A table with a text field above it, the table shows matches in the database:

```
<script>
$('#searchRecept > #searchReceptAjax').keyup(function(){//Werkt dit?

    var postRecept = $.post("../ajaxhandler.php?action=searchRecept", $('#searchRecept').serialize());
    postRecept.done(function( data ) {
        var response = $("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('tbody');
        $('#recepten > tbody').replaceWith( response );
    });
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine. Before that I created a link (one in every row of the tbody) to insert a new row after that row:

```
<script>
    $('.addingredient').click(function(e){
    $('<tr><td colspan="5">test</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));                    
    });
</script>
```

The tbody looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Something...</td>
        <td>Something else.</td>
        <td>Probably some text here.</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>???</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="addingredient">aap</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I used the same php include in ajaxhandler.php (to create response) as on the initial page request - with other contents of course.
However, after the tbody is changed by the first piece of javascript adding a row doesn't work anymore. Even if the tbody that comes from the response has the same data as in the initial request (when search string is empty).

Why doesn't this work? Any thoughts?

Kinds regards,

Niels

Comment: Use event delegation. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to attach events for dynamically created elements:

```
$('body').on('click','.addingredient', function(e){
    $('<tr><td colspan="5">test</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));                    
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.

Just for my understanding: the way I did it I created an event (click) for all elements with '.addingredient' that existed at that time... Newly created elements didn't get that action, but now because I'm looking for elements inside the <body> it does work.

Correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You can also find out more informations about event delegation with the link I've provided in the answer.